# Selecting a single rows ng-model using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using `ng-repeat`, I have given a row an `ng-model` value of `patentAppData.defaultSelect`. I need to reset `select` elements within this row, and have achieved this by doing so:

```
$scope.transactionListFilter = function(data, filter, i) {

    if(filter == 'clientRefFilter') {
        $scope.filter = data;
        $scope.patentAppData.defaultSelect = null;    
    } else {
        $scope.filter = data;
        $scope.clientRefData.defaultSelect = null;          
    }                   
}

<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <select ng-options="item.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber for item in row.renewalUIs" ng-change="transactionListFilter(patentAppData.defaultSelect, 'patentAppFilter', row.id)" ng-model="patentAppData.defaultSelect" >
</tr>

<select ng-options="item.patentUI.clientRef for item in row.renewalUIs" ng-change="transactionListFilter(clientRefData.defaultSelect, 'clientRefFilter', row.id)"  ng-model="clientRefData.defaultSelect" >
    <option value="">Multiple</option>
</select>
```

When a user selects one of the drop downs, the idea is that the other one resets to its default value of `multiple`. It does this, but an error as occurred where the others rows `select` options display nothing. No default value of `multiple`, which is should do if it is reset to null,and no values from the model.

It should work as so:

```
`row1` `multiple` `ID0001` //the user has selected the second column, which resets the first columns select value to multiple
---------------------------
`row2` `multiple` `multiple`
```

What is happening:

```
`row1` `multiple` `ID0001`
---------------------------
`row2` `multiple` `      ` //the controller is resetting all other rows connected to the model to blank
```

***Question***

How do I correct my script so only the model for that row is adjusted?